# Flexbox for nested items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a graph from divs. The outermost div is a flexbox and it has nested divs for nodes in it. They are nested because every node recursively creates its child nodes. I want the nodes to be horizontally next to each other, but for some reason each one is in its own row. Additionally, for some reason, the second node is not overlapping the first but every other is overlapping its parent a bit.
What am I doing wrong and is there a way to use flexbox for such a nested graph?

```css
.graph {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.node {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
  <div class="node">
    <p>3</p>
    <div class="node">
      <p>2</p>
      <div class="node">
        <p>1</p>
        <div class="node">
          <p>0</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the CSS display: contents setting and still use flex.

This snippet moves the formatting to the child of each node and sets the node itself to `display: contents`. This means its children are considered by the flex.

```css
.graph {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.node {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
  <div class="node">
    <p>3</p>
    <div class="node">
      <p>2</p>
      <div class="node">
        <p>1</p>
        <div class="node">
          <p>0</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but there is no proper way to do it. Because you can't use `Flexbox` or `Grid` layout models here. So my suggestion is to use `position:absolute` property.
I hope my answer is helpful to you.

```css
.flex{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
 }
.margin{
  margin-left:50px;
}
.node {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph flex">
   <div class="node flex ">
      <p>3</p>
      <div class="node flex margin">
         <p>2</p>
         <div class="node flex margin">
            <p>1</p>
            <div class="node flex margin">
               <p>0</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel you can use flex if you introduce the display: contents CSS on the nodes - this means their children can be considered by the flex.

Comment: @AHaworth I saw your answer. I appreciate your answer sir. It's very helpful to us. Thank you.

Comment: @maba please consider sir's answer.

Answer (score -1):

In my understanding you want something like this. The issue in your code is that you use flex on graph when node added in graph flex property apply on it but when next node added in node it don't inherit flex property because it don't contain flex property.

```css
.graph {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.node {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 55px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:first-child {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="graph">
  <div class="node">
    <p>3</p>
    <div class="node">
      <p>2</p>
      <div class="node">
        <p>1</p>
        <div class="node">
          <p>0</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that this would fix my problem, but since every node recursively creates its childs, it cannot create them outside of the div at the same level.

Comment: @maba I changed my script maybe it will help you now.

Comment: @Nisha nice code  by the way, looks similar to mine.

Comment: @maba please consider AHaworth answer, It's a perfect solution for your problem.

Comment: @mr.Hritik maybe it's similar but I didn't copy from you.